# How can I just get an IfxBlob from am Informix query in .net?

Tags: vb.net, informix

I can't seem to find a way to get just the locator object of a column under .Net. It seems that Informix is automatically converting the blob column to Byte[] and not leaving a way to change that behavior.

```
IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection c = 
           new IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection("...");
c.Open();
IBM.Data.Informix.IfxCommand cmd = 
           new IBM.Data.Informix.IfxCommand("SELECT id,data FROM aaa", c);
IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (r.Read()) {
    Debug.WriteLine(r.GetValue(1).GetType());
}

c.Close();
```

results:

```
System.Byte[]
System.Byte[]
System.DBNull
System.DBNull
```

I expected:

```
IBM.Data.Informix.IfxBlob
```

or something similar.

Comment: What is the type of the column in the table in the database?  If it is BYTE or BLOB, then why would there be a need to invent an IBM.Data.Informix.IfxBlob type instead?  (There could be good reasons; I am by no stretch of anyone's imagination a .NET expert.)

Comment: The type is "create table aaa(id serial,data blob) put data in 'sbspace'.

IfxBlob is a type in the .Net driver.

What I want to do is know if there is a blob, but get it on demand. effectively lazy load the data.  Changing the schema is out of the question as its a very large legacy system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a colleague about this, and this is his response to me.  Since it isn't my handiwork, I've made the answer 'Community Wiki' so I don't get the credit (beyond knowing where to ask).

---

To answer the question...  the following program was written using the Common Informix Provider (the IBM.Data.Informix.dll which uses the DRDA communication protocol...  you can get it in the "IBM Data Server Driver for CLI, ODBC, and .NET" package).   Something very similar should be able to be done with the Legacy Informix Provider (the IBM.Data.Informix.dll which uses the SQLI communication protocol... you can get it in the "Informix Client SDK" package).

Here's an example program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using IBM.Data.Informix;

namespace InformixClob
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         try
         {
            IfxConnection tConn = new IfxConnection("database=idsdb;server=my-system:9089;uid=informix;pwd=********");
            tConn.Open();

            IfxCommand tCmd = tConn.CreateCommand();
            // create table mytesttab (col1 integer, col2 clob)
            tCmd.CommandText = "select * from mytesttab";
            IfxDataReader tRdr = tCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (tRdr.Read())
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Col1 is a {0}", tRdr.GetValue(0).GetType());
               Console.WriteLine("Col2(GetValue) is a {0}", tRdr.GetValue(1).GetType());
               Console.WriteLine("Col2(GetIfxValue) is a {0}", tRdr.GetIfxValue(1).GetType());
               Console.WriteLine("Col2(GetIfxClob) is a {0}", tRdr.GetIfxClob(1).GetType());
            }
            tRdr.Close();
            tConn.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
         }
         finally
         {
            Console.Write("Press ENTER"); Console.ReadLine();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And here's the output it generates:

```
Col1 is a System.Int32
Col2(GetValue) is a System.String
Col2(GetIfxValue) is a IBM.Data.Informix.IfxClob
Col2(GetIfxClob) is a IBM.Data.Informix.IfxClob
Press ENTER
```

The `IfxDataReader.GetValue(int)` method is going to return the column value in a native .NET Framework data type.   To get the column value returned as an Informix type, you must request that it be returned as such by either calling the `GetIfxValue(int)` method, or if you can be more specific, by the `GetIfxClob(int)` method.